# prevent part of array saving to localStorage in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to prevent resultComment being saved into localStorage, how can I achieve that? Currently when I delete localStorage data from browser and calculate result, result gets pushed to my resultHistory array and only the result and temperatureUnit gets saved to localStorage which I want, but on the second calculation now also the resultComment gets saved. How can I prevent this or what can be done differently? Here is StackBlitz:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mdhnnt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Steps to recreate problem:

1. Clear localStorage data and refresh page,
2. type number in both inputs and click on button -> result and unit gets saved.
3. Now type different numbers in inputs and  click on button -> and now the resultComment gets saved as well). Ignore weird calculation results. Its missing parts which I didn't add to StackBlitz.

component ts

```
 class HistoryResult {
  constructor(
    public result: number,
    public temperatureUnit: string,
    public resultComment?: string
  ) {}
}
  resultHistory: HistoryResult[] = []; 

//in ngOnInit iam initializing resultHistory so it stays on page when i refresh and adding comment to each result
ngOnInit() {
...
..code..
...
    this.resultHistory = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('result')) || [];
    this.resultHistory.map((item) => {
      item.resultComment = this.heatIndexService.determineComment(
        item.result,
        item.temperatureUnit
      );
    });
}
onCalculateButtonClick(): void {
    this.result = null;
    this.resultTemperatureUnit = this.temperatureUnit.value;
    if (this.heatIndexForm.invalid) {
      this.heatIndexForm.controls['temperature'].markAsDirty();
      this.heatIndexForm.controls['humidity'].markAsDirty();
      return;
    }
    this.result = this.heatIndexService.calculateHeatIndex(
      this.temperatureValue,
      this.humidityValue,
      this.resultTemperatureUnit.code
    );
    this.heatIndexService.saveResultInLocalStorage(
      this.result,
      this.temperatureUnit.value.code,
      this.resultHistory
    );
    this.resultHistory.map((item) => {
      item.resultComment = this.heatIndexService.determineComment(
        item.result,
        item.temperatureUnit
      );
    });
  }
```

service functions

```
  saveResultInLocalStorage(
    result: number,
    unit: string,
    historyResults: HistoryResult[]
  ): void {
    // Check if result is the same as last one
    if (
      historyResults.length === 0 ||
      historyResults.slice(-1)[0].result !== result
    ) {
      historyResults.push(new HistoryResult(result, unit));
      // Remove oldest result if more than 3 results
      if (historyResults.length > 3) {
        historyResults.shift();
      }
      localStorage.setItem('result', JSON.stringify(historyResults));
    }
  }

  determineComment(temperature: number, units: string): string {
    if (units === 'C') {
      temperature = (temperature * 9) / 5 + 32;
    }
    if (temperature >= 75 && temperature <= 90) {
      return 'Caution: fatigue is possible with prolonged exposure and activity. Continuing activity could result in heat cramps.';
    } else if (temperature > 90 && temperature <= 105) {
      return 'Extreme caution: heat cramps and heat exhaustion are possible. Continuing activity could result in heat stroke.';
    } else if (temperature > 105 && temperature <= 130) {
      return 'Danger: heat cramps and heat exhaustion are likely; heat stroke is probable with continued activity.';
    } else {
      return 'Extreme danger: heat stroke is imminent.';
    }
  }
```

and HTML where the previous calculations are shown

```
  <p-table [value]="resultHistory" [tableStyle]="{'min-width': '50rem'}">
      <ng-template pTemplate="header">
          <tr>
              <th>Heat Index</th>
              <th class="heat-index-effect">Effect on the body</th>
          </tr>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-history>
          <tr>
              <td>{{history.result | number : '1.2-2'}}&deg;{{history.temperatureUnit}}</td>
              <td>{{history.resultComment}}</td>
          </tr>
      </ng-template>
  </p-table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Opening question response

You are mutating the array when calling `this.historyResults.map(...)` and then saving that value in `saveResultInLocalStorage` when calling `localStorage.setItem(historyResults)`.

Change your value to be saved as a new array with only the properties you want then call `localStorage.setItem(newValue)`.

To pick out only the properties you want and save them you could do the following:

```js
const resultsToSave: Pick<HistoryResult, 'result' | 'temperatureUnit'>[] = historyResults.map(h => ({ result: h.result, temperatureUnit: h.temperatureUnit }));
localStorage.setItem('result', JSON.stringify(resultsToSave));
```

An alternative to using `Pick` above to get the reduced type could be to use `Omit` which may be shorter depending on how many fields you specify, e.g.:

```js
const resultsToSave: Omit<HistoryResult, 'resultComment'>[] = historyResults.map(h => ({ result: h.result, temperatureUnit: h.temperatureUnit }));
```

### First comment response

When you `.map()` over the history results it looks like you aren't reassigning the value correctly. Try returning a new object when iterating over the array and saving it back to itself.

From this:

```js
this.resultHistory.map((item) => {
  item.resultComment = this.determineComment(
    item.result,
    item.temperatureUnit
  );
});
```

To this:

```js
this.resultHistory = this.resultHistory.map((item) => ({
  ...item,
  resultComment: this.determineComment(
    item.result,
    item.temperatureUnit
  ),
}));
```

Comment: Yes that works just fine, thanks! But now it adds new resultHistory object to the array in localStorage instead of just changing the values when different result was calculated and keeping just 1 object there with different temperature and unit. Not that its a issue but is there a different solution for that too ?

Comment: @mato4899 I've updated the answer and hope that resolves your comment